# How to ThenInclude all in a hierarchy?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have an object called a Market which may have 0-many other submarkets, which all use the Market object and are stored in the same table as their parent.

Since a submarket can have its own set of subdivisions, and there is no business limit as to how many levels there could exist, how would you build an EF query to get all possible nested subdivisions and any children?

My current approach would have me build a query that looks like:

```
        using var property_context = new PropertyContext();
        var branchIds = branches.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
        property_context.Markets.Where(x => branchIds.Contains(x.BranchId??0))
            .Include(x => x.Children)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Children)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Children)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Children);
                            ...
```

but I'm hoping that there is a better way, maybe something like `.RecurInclude(x => x.Children)`

Comment: No way and not planned [Support loading recursive relationships to any depth](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/14144)